# systemd oneshot service to block the user login prompt

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a oneshot systemd service, that needs to start a process, but i dont want the user to have the login prompt until its finished, tried this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Stap Loader.
After=network-online.target
Before=systemd-logind.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
LimitNOFILE=8192
ExecStart=/opt/stap/stap start
ExecStop=/opt/stap/stap stop
StandardOutput=journal+console
RemainAfterExit=yes
TTYVTDisallocate=true
TTYReset=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This doesnt work.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work. what do you mean? It doesn't run at all? It runs, but not until after the user logs in? Are there any error messages? You're going to need to provide for information before we can start to help you here.

Comment: It runs, but the login prompt arrives anyway when its still running (any yes, im sure its 'oneshot')

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it with:

```
Before=getty@tty1.service
```

As this will be used only from tty (VMWare Console or bare metal)